# Why can't i change a objects attributes from a method

Tags: swift, oop, object, methods, attributes

I wrote this in swift, and I am new to OOP:

```
class dis{
    var dist = 0
    func run(){
        dist += 1
    }
}

dis().run()
dis().run()
dis().run()
dis().run()
dis().run()
dis().run()

print(dis().dist())
```

I expected to print 6 but it printed 0. Why did this happen and how can I fix it.

Comment: *Hint:* Each `dis()` call creates a *new instance* ...

Comment: *Remark:* Class names should start with a capital letter, e.g. `class Dis`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what happens in `dis().run()`:

- `dis()` creates and returns a "dis" object using the default constructor: all instance variables are set to their initial
  value, in your case `dist` is set to zero.
- The `run()` method is called on this object. The method increases
  the value of `list` by one, but now ...
- ... the object is destroyed because there is no reference to it.

The next `dis().run()` call creates a *new* object, and so on.

The final `print(dis().dist)` call again creates a new object 
(again with `dist` set to zero).

What you probably want is to create one object, keep a reference to it, and call the `run()` method on this object repeatedly:

```
let d = dis()
d.run()
d.run()
d.run()
d.run()
d.run()
d.run()
print(d.dist) // 6
```

Comment: Great explanation..:)

Comment: @DharmeshKheni: Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this: you just need to make that function return the increment number, and every time you create a new **dis()** the counter gets back to zero. 
Try this:

```
class dis
{
   var dist = 0

    func run()->Int
    {
       dist += 1
       return dist
    }
 }

 var d = dis()
 print("\(d.run()) \n")  //<--- do this 6 times you will see the result
```